# How to prove that it is a topology on this set?

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that this  $$D_n=\{p\in E, p|n\}$$ can define a topology on the set $$E=\{n\in\mathbb{N}, n\geq2\}$$

Comment: Do you mean that these are the sets in the topology or that $D_n$ form a basis for the topology?

Comment: Have you started with the axioms? Is $\emptyset$ in $D_n$ for any $n$? If you say $D_1 = \emptyset$, then yes. Next, let $\mathcal{T} = \{D_n,n\ge 1\}$. Is $E \in \mathcal{T}$? Because a topology requires the full set be there. Then, for any subset $\mathcal{T}' \subset \mathcal{T}$, do you have $\bigcup_{D_n \in \mathcal{T'}} D_n \in \mathcal{T}$? Can you take unions?
Finally, you need finite intersections (you can just show that you can take the intersection of any two arbitrary sets $D_n$ and that suffices).

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: Why $n\ge 1$?

Comment: @celtschk because without $n=1$, you do not get the empty set.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe i don't know how to obtain $E$ in the topology, and also what is the intersection an the union i don't know how to use p is a devisor of 2

Comment: @Poline Sandra, let $P = \{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,\ldots \} = \{2,3,5,7,\ldots \}$ be the set of prime numbers. First show that $D_{p_k} \subset D_{p_k^n}$ for any prime $p_k$. Next, show that $D_{p_k} \subset D_{np_k}$ for any $n\in \mathbb{E}$ and any prime $p_k$. 

Then, because $\mathcal{T} = \displaystyle \bigcup_{n\ge 1}\{D_n\}$, use the prime factorization theorem to show that you can find a tower of proper subsets of $D_n$'s by multiplying by prime powers and increasing the powers of each prime already in the list. Example:

Comment: $D_{p_1^1} \subsetneq D_{p_1^2p_2^2} \subsetneq D_{p_1^3p_2^3p_3^3} \subsetneq \cdots$

Use that to show that the limit of this tower must be $E$.

Comment: what  is $p_k^n$ ?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: I actually meant, why do you exclude $n=0$.

Comment: @celtschk that is a good point. If you include $n=0$, that instantly gives you $E$.

Comment: @Poline Sandra it is the $k$-th prime number taken to the $n$-th power. Have you not seen subscript and power notation before?

Comment: No i don't understant this set at all, what i understand in the comments is that $D_0=E$, $D_1=\emptyset$ and the topology may be all the union of the sets $D_n$ @InterstellarProbe

Comment: You have $p_k$ is the $k$-th prime number. For example, if $k=1$, then $p_k=2$. 

$D_2 = \{n\in E, n|2\} = \{2\}$ because 2 is the only divisor of 2 that is greater than 1.

Now, if we consider $p_1^5$, we are looking for the divisors of $2^5=32$. Thus 

$D_{p_1^5} = D_{32} = \{2^1,2^2,2^3,2^4,2^5\} = \{2,4,8,16,32\}$

Answer (score 0):

@Osama Ghani asked, this question really boils down to whether you are looking for the basis of a topology or the topology itself. If you are looking for the topology itself, then no, the set of all such $D_n$'s is not a topology.

To prove it, let $\mathcal{T} = \{D_n, n\in \mathbb{N} \}$. Then $D_2 = \{2\}$ and $D_3 = \{3\}$, but $D_2 \cup D_3 = \{2,3\} \notin \mathcal{T}$ since any number divisible by 2 and 3 is at least 6, and so would also be divisible by 6. (We can check 2,3,4,5 and show that none of them are divisible by both 2 and 3, and any number larger than 5 that is divisible by 2 and 3 is also divisible by 6).

But, if you were to define $\mathcal{B} = \{D_n, n\in \mathbb{N} \}$ and take all intersections and finite unions, you can easily show you would have a topology. But, that is how you can extend any subset of the powerset of a set into a topology on that set, so there is nothing special about sets of divisors.

Comment: can you explain me more,  i steal don't know how to solve this exercise

Comment: To prove that the set $\{D_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ forms a basis for a topology, you need the following:
1. For each $e\in E$, there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $e\in D_n$. To prove this, use $D_e$ since every natural number divides itself.

2. For any $e\in E$ and $n_1,n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $e \in D_{n_1}\cap D_{n_2}$, there exists $n_3 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $e \in D_{n_3} \subset D_{n_1}\cap D_{n_2}$ (hint: think GCD).